# java.io.FileNotFoundException With jmeter testplan while running it from Jenkins-Maven build

Tags: maven, file-upload, jenkins, jmeter

I am using File Upload (Post) Rest API in jmeter. file Path in the file upload section I have given as "File name" directly as its in the same folder where jmx file is.

Its working fine in jmeter ui but when running it through Jenkins I am getting file not found Exception.

how ever I am not sure whether I need to update anything in POM file or my jmx file it self to make jenkins find file path.

```
Current Scenario Jmeter:
jmx file location: xyz/test.jmx
Fie upload location: xyz/abc.file
file path in Jmeter UI(HTTP POST request): abc.file
Result: Working Fine

Current Scenario Jenkins:
jmx file location: xyz/src/test/jmeter/test.jmx
Fie upload location: xyz/src/test/jmeter/abc.file
file path in Jmeter UI(HTTP POST request): abc.file
Result: getting file not found exception
```

please suggest me solution if any I have already checked many blogs/answers. but none of them result my situation.

Thanks,
Divyang Raval

Comment: Got the solution suggested by Dmitri T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when JMeter is being run from Maven it tries to look for files under the following folder:

```
target\jmeter\bin
```

So the options are in:

- use full path instead of relative
- copy the file from its original location to `target\jmeter\bin` folder using i.e. [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) from [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)
- given you don't execute `mvn clean` copy the file to `target\jmeter\bin` folder once

The best solution would be using [Jenkins Parameterisation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build), i.e. pass  **WORKSPACE** [Jenkins Variable](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) property value to Maven build and access it in JMeter via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

Comment: Excellent Dmitri. I have copied file to target/jmeter/bin folder and it worked..!!